# AWS Instance Scheduler: A couple of questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, aws-cloudformation, scheduler

I am setting up and testing a Cloud Formation instance scheduling stack and I want to make sure I completely understand the effect of these settings:

--retain-running

--enforced

--override-status

The AWS documentation is not completely clear (to me !)

1. the first two are Boolean. Does leaving them out of a schedule have the same effect as putting them in and setting them to 'false'?
2. I am not clear on what 'retain-running' actually means?
3. I am not clear on what 'override-status' actually means?
4. I am assuming 'enforced' means that a state change will be effected 'no matter what' (other rules may dictate)

I am new to AWS and this level of detail. So please reply with a couple of examples of ho the above settings would be used. Much appreciated

I have tried different cim=binations of the above settings. Some times I get the result I want and then sometimes I don't

By objective is a simple template to shut down EC2 instances overnight and start them up again in the morning.

This is the schedule I have now:

```
{
  "description": {
    "S": "EST work hours"
  },
  "enforced": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "hibernate": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "name": {
    "S": "EST-office-hours"
  },
  "periods": {
    "SS": [
      "all-days",
      "all-days2"
    ]
  },
  "retain_running": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "stop_new_instances": {
    "BOOL": true
  },
  "timezone": {
    "S": "America/New_York"
  },
  "type": {
    "S": "schedule"
  },
  "use_maintenance_window": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "use_metrics": {
    "BOOL": false
  }
}
```